# how can we resolve Error in plugin "gulp-shell"?

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-shell

After running gulp-server command, i am getting below error.
'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[13:04:36] 'clear' errored after 60 ms
[13:04:36] Error in plugin "gulp-shell"
Message:
Command `rm -rf ./public/index.html ./public/testem.js` failed with exit code 1
Details:
domainEmitter: [object Object]
domain: [object Object]
domainThrown: false
[13:04:36] 'server' errored after 63 ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me error got solved after I executed commands using `git bash`.